# Problems using Entity Framework in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I've created an ASP.Net web application using VS 2017. Now I'm trying to use Entity Framework to connect to a database.

- I've added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model named `TestDBModel.edmx`
- I've added a connection to my database file `Test.mdf` and named the entity connection settings `TestEntities`
- I've selected the tables I want to use and named the model namespace `TestModel`
- After a few seconds the designer shows the diagram with all the tables I've selected before
- Now I want to get access to the tables using for example this code:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
  using TestModel;

  namespace Test
  {
      public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
      {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              TestEntities entities = new TestEntities();
              GridView1.DataSource = entities.Departments;
              GridView1.DataBind();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This is the way the manual (Beginning ASP.NET 4.5 in C#) told me to do.

But the line `using TestModel;` creates an error because he can't find the namespace `TestModel`. Thereby the next lines also creates errors because of the missing namespace.

If I look at the properties of the designer, it shows me the namespace `TestModel` and also the entity name `TestEntities`.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There may be a "helper"/tooltip dropdown that appears for `TestEntities` in code if VisualStudio can "guess" what it's namespace should be, and give you an option to add that namespace. Mouse over `TestEntities();`

Comment: Is the edmx in the same project?

Comment: By default, the model does not get a new namespace.  Expand your edmx container in Solution Explorer, expand your Context.tt, and look at the namespace declaration in Context.cs.  Can you just remove the using TestModel and try again?

Comment: This is interesting. As many tutorials describes you have to add the namespace via the using keyword. As you said the namespace from the Model is still the same as the project. Confusing because you explicity create an extra namespace during the creation of the edmx-file and also the designer told you this namespace. After removing "using TestModel" the rest of the code still wont work because I have to restart VS. Very confusing. Many thanks for the hint! Now I got another error when I open the page but this looks feasible.